# How to integrate over domain $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R^3}:x\leq\sqrt3y,y\leq\sqrt3x,xy\leq z\leq1\}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Consider the domain $D=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R^3}:x\leq\sqrt3y,y\leq\sqrt3x,xy\leq z\leq1\}$, and calculate the following integral:

$$\iiint_Dxye^{-z}dxdydz$$

I'm having trouble figuring that domain out, and hence how to integrate over it. Since we have $x\leq3x$ and $y\leq3y$, we deduce both have to be on the first quadrant (if they were negative, we'd have $3x<x$ and $3y<y)$.

I decided, not sure if correctly or not, to compute the iterated integral with respect to $z$ first, since its range is an interval, and hence:

$$\int_{xy}^{1}e^{-z}dz=e^{-xy}-e^{-1}$$

Not sure how to compute the other two as I don't know where they're "moving", not even sure whether this first step was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x \ge 0$, $y \ge 0$ as you pointed out.

Now, note that $xy \le z \le 1$, so that $y \le 1/x$. Then we have:

$$\begin{cases} 
x \le \sqrt3 y \\
y \le \sqrt3 x \\
y \le 1/x
\end{cases}$$

If you draw these graphs, you will see that there is an enclosed region.

Comment: Thanks, so does that mean computing the first iterated integral was correct?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes it was correct.

Comment: Perfect, problem solved.